# Is there a webcrawler that can download an entire site?

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink

Need to know if there is a crawler/downloader that can crawl and download and entire website with at least a link depth of 4 pages. The site I am trying to download has java script hyperlinks that are rendered only by a browser and thus the crawler is unable crawl these hyperlinks unless the crawler itself renders them!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive used Teleport Pro and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Metaproducts Offline Explorer boasts doing what you need.